# Connecting an image with referral links

Tags: php, url, referrals

Generally, when we share a link on Facebook, it fetches a preview. 
**What I want is that when users share their referral link from my website the preview fetched should be an image.**
Look at the examples below.
The one which fetches an image.
https://dollartube.ositracker.com/92606/7380

The one that doesn't fetch the image
https://www.dollartube.com/index.php/signup?ref=ab93974134f7b971

**Is it possible to change the link so some image is fetched as a preview?** I believe it is something we can control. Just not getting the idea where to start.

Comment: You mean OpenGraphProtocol? http://ogp.me/

Comment: @kerbholz not exactly, try pasting these link on facebook, As soon you post the facebook fetches a preview. what i want is that the preview fetched should be an image, like in first link. second one is link of my website

Comment: I don't have Facebook, but I think `<meta property="og:image"..>` is what you're after, a screenshot/preview image of your site.

Comment: let me try this @kerbholz